# Get the files chosen using the input type file (multiple) and store them in an array

Tags: javascript, dom, input

In my HTML i select multiple files.

```
<input type="file" id="img" multiple>
```

I want to store each element in an array so that i can print the file source.

I have done this in my javascript but it does not work.

```
function loadfiles()
{
var x=document.getElementById("img");
for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
  document.write(x.elements[i].src);
}
}
```

Comment: ID's are supposed to be unique.

Comment: so whats the question ?

Comment: also, `document.write` cannot be used after the page has loaded. Use `document.createElement`, `document.createTextNode` and `Element#appendChild`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property `files` gets you an array of all the files selected by the file input. So the loadfiles function should be modified to following:

```
function loadfiles()
{
    var imageFiles = document.getElementById("img"),
    filesLength = imageFiles.files.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
      document.write(imageFiles.files[i].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: .name shows the name of the file . I want to get the Source or PATH of the file. what to do ?

Comment: Browsers restrict recovering the file path for security reasons. This was available in old browsers but the browsers supporting HTML5 now sends a `C:\fakepath\` in the path name. So its better not to rely on something which is not available across all major browsers. @insanity

Answer (score 2):

DOM documentation (Mozilla):

> `element = document.getElementById(id);`
>
> where
>
> - `element` is a reference to an Element object, or null if an element with the specified ID is not in the document.
> - `id` is a case-sensitive string representing the unique ID of the element being sought.

In your code `document.getElementById(id)` returns a single element and not a list.
To access the files added to the input take a look at the HTML5 Files API.

```
var f = (document.getElementById('img').files);
for (var i =0; i < f.length; i++){
   var new_div = document.createElement('div');
   new_div.innerHTML = f[i].name;
   document.body.appendChild(new_div);   
}
```

FYI: Using `document.write()` is extremely dangerous, and should be avoided. For more read this stackoverflow Q&A: [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

In the example above I substituted `document.write` with `document.body.appendChild`

**Fiddle (with jQuery)**: http://jsfiddle.net/4Yq4F/

#### Getting the complete file path

This is in your response requesting for the complete file path of the files. Unfortunately due to security reasons this is **not** possible as of now. Mozilla Firefox browsers however will provide you with the complete file path with the `mozFullPath` attribute. If you want to use it, in the above example substitute `f[i].name` with `f[i].mozFullPath`

Comment: .name shows the name of the file . I want to get the Source or PATH of the file. what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you...

```
function loadfiles()
{
    var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
         if(x[i].type == "file"){
             document.write(x[i].value);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will be work for you.

*HTML*

```
<input type="text" id="text"/>
<input type="button" value="add" id="adda"/>
```

*JavaScript*

```
var arry=[];
$("#adda").click(function(){
   arry.push( $("#text").val());
    alert(arry);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileArray = new Array();
 $('#inputPostFile').change(function() {
                var files = this.files;
                   $('.uploadedFileList').html('');
                $.each(files, function (index, value) {
                    fileArray.push(value);
                });
            });
```