# I want to work with array name in change function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, arraylist

I want to check its valid image or not.
My code valid image is as follow and its work perfects but, when its image array then it doesn't work?

```
$("#file").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'gif': case 'jpg': case 'png':
            //alert("an image");
            break;
        default:
            $(this).val('');
            // error message here
            alert("Please Select Valid Image");
            break;
    }

});
```

its work perfect for one image means its work on id but now I want to work with image array then what I do ? its possible or not?

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="images[]">Enter 8 Images For Batter Product View
<input type="button" id="addmore" value="Add More Image">
```

in add more image its give me the new image so I take an array so I want to check in the array this change function its valid image or not?
is it possible?

thanks

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400191/get-the-files-chosen-using-the-input-type-file-multiple-and-store-them-in-an-a

Answer (score 0):

Inputs of type `file` have an attribute called [**files**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_files.asp) which is an array of the files the user selects. It contains information such as names and sizes. You can loop through them and check if the user have entered a valid image or not, like this:

```
$("#file").change(function() {
    var files = this.files; // get the array of files
    var valid = true;

    for(var i = 0; i < files.length && valid; i++) { // while there still files in the array, and valid still true
        var val = files[i].name; // get the current filename

        // check if the file is a valid image or not (if not don't forget to set valid to false)
        switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
            case 'gif': case 'jpg': case 'png':
                // this is a valid image
            break;
            default:
                // this is not a valid image so "valid" should become false
                valid = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!valid) // if valid was set to false insde the array (means an invalid file was selected)
        alert("select valid images");
});
```

**Note:** checking if the files are images on the client side isn't always effective, the user could by-pass your check by changing the extension name of a file that isn't an image to, for example, `.jpg`. Read more [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828554/how-to-allow-input-type-file-to-accept-only-image-files)!

Comment: thanks for replr sir .how to check .jpg in valid ? sir

Comment: @Darshan Just the way you had it! Just put you switch instead of my comment! But as I said checking just the extention isn't always effective!

Comment: @Darshan I added your switch statement where it should be!

Comment: @Darshan check this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6225815/6647153) you won't need any of the above. Just set the attribute `accept` of the input! No validation whatsoever is needed!

Comment: thank you so much sir but i have to work this code i haven't any option so i do it sir

Comment: i put your code but its always valid true its give alert but its accept any file

Comment: i put your code but its always valid true its give alert but its accept any file and my be its check in first file of image may be for id ? not work in second file ?

Answer (score 0):

I have simply change `id="file"` to `class="file"` and it works for me.

```
<input class="file" type="file" name="images[]">Enter 8 Images For Batter Product View

<input type="button" id="addmore" value="Add More Image">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".file").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'gif': case 'jpg': case 'png':
            //alert("an image");
            break;
        default:
            $(this).val('');
            // error message here
            alert("Please Select Valid Image");
            break;
    }

});
```

Comment: its work only first time when its first image valid then ts add valid in all tag <input class="file valid" type="file" name="images[]">